# May I call <algorithm> facilities on empty ranges?

Tags: c++, iterator, undefined-behavior

I mean, is it valid to write something like that:

```
std::vector<int> vec(100, 0);
auto it = std::find(vec.end(), vec.end(), 5);
```

Is `it` guaranteed to be `vec.end()` or this is some sort of UB?

It will save me some case checking if this construct is allowed.

Comment: Should be fine.

Comment: That case is explicitly mentioned in the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Comment: @tobi303 in case of an empty vector `begin() == end()`

Comment: @manni66 d'oh, my mistake ;)

Comment: @tobi303 -- a range is defined by a pair of iterators: [it0, it1). If the two iterators are equal, the range is empty. It doesn't matter whether they come from the middle of a container, the end of a container, or from some other source.

Comment: @nwp Where? I may be blind, but I can't see it under the link you provided.

Comment: "Return value: Iterator to the first element satisfying the condition or last if no such element is found." Since you passed in `vec.end(), vec.end()` there can be no element found so it is guaranteed to return `vec.end()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pair of iterators such as `vec.end(), vec.end()` is an **empty** range but it is still a **valid** range. You can call a function on an empty range. Supplying valid range to algorithm functions does not invoke undefined behavior. As described in the possible [implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) the `std::find` function will simply skip this part:

```
 for (; first != last; ++first) {
     if (!q(*first)) {
         return first;
     }
 }
```

and return the `last` iterator:

```
return last;
```